# Does input space size contribute at all to the runtime of an algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory

I just started learning about NP-Complete problems and one of the first examples they give is Set Cover:

> Given a set $U$ of $n$ elements, a collection $S_1, \ldots, S_m$ of subsets of $U$, and a number $k$, does there exist a collection of at least $k$ of these sets with the property that not two of them intersect?

This is I'm sure a very basic question, but I was wondering whether the amount of space in $n$ the *input* takes up matters at all in the formulation of runtime. This is the first example of an algorithm I've seen where the input itself takes up space exponential in $n$ since of course there are $2^n$ possible subsets of $U$. Thus, it seems that possibly the time needed to allocate the space necessary to even "handle" the input prevents there from being a polynomial time algorithm.

Or rather, do we just assume that the input magically appears in our hands already allocated before we start keeping track of algorithm runtime? And as a side question, can we choose what data structure it is given to us in? This seems more natural to me, but I wanted to make sure. I know, for example, that the time needed to allocate an *output* (or allocate anything in between) does matter.

Comment: Your program doesn't have to read all possible 2^n subsets of U; just the ones provided as input. The input for this problem is a set of size n, m sets of size at most n, and one scalar number, which can all be read in time polynomial in m and n; more generally, when talking about a "polynomial time" algorithm, that means polynomial in the input size, and it is surely impossible for the input size to be exponential in itself.

Comment: @kaya3 Thanks for the response! I still have a question though: With this formulation, wouldn't Set Cover be solvable in polynomial time? All I have to do is iterate over the ${m \choose k}$ subsets of size $k$ of $\{ S_1, \ldots , S_m  \}$ and for each collection of subsets check whether no two of them intersect. Checking for intersections in each iteration would I believe take $O(n^2 m^2)$, though that might be off. Regardless it seems to be polynomial. The key fact being we don't need to check collections of size greater than $k$ since if there is a collection of size...

Comment: @kaya3 ...greater than $k$ where no two $S_i$ intersect then there is a collection of size exactly $k$ where no two intersect.

Comment: In general (m choose k) is polynomial in m but exponential in k, and the number of bits needed to describe the input (i.e. m sets of size <= n, plus the scalar k) is not exponential in k.

Comment: @kaya3 Ah I'm so used to the second part of the choose operation being a constant that I forgot it is actually exponential. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We measure the running time as a function of the length of the input, not as a function of $n$.  So, it doesn't matter whether the length of the input is $2^n$ or not.

When we talk about an exponential-time function, we normally mean exponential in the length of the input, not exponential in some other parameter (like $n$).

For your problem, the length of the input could be $2^n$, but it will typically be a lot less than $2^n$, because typically we'll have many fewer sets than that.  Either way, it doesn't matter, because we're measuring the running time as a function of the input length.

Typically, the format/representation of the input doesn't affect the running time much; the running time will be identical for any reasonable way to represent or encode the input.  So, typically that doesn't matter.  In the cases where it *does* matter, be careful to specify the input representation, or ask if it isn't specified.